# Visual studio 2017 navigation bar too long

Tags: visual-studio

I have some methods which have many parameters. Look what VS navigation bar shows me.

[image: Navigation bar]

It aligns members to the right and I can't see names. Is there a way to left-align it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting the PC it got it right!!

[image]